# Flink Job ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to run a Flink job using Apache Flink version 1.16.2, and I'm encountering the following error when executing my job using `./bin/flink run /Users/spartacus/icu-alarm/target/flink-kafka-stroke-risk-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/source/KafkaSource
    at hes.cs63.CEPMonitor.StrokeRiskAlarm.main(StrokeRiskAlarm.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:240)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 14 more
```

I believe this error is related to missing dependencies or a classpath issue. Here's the relevant part of my code that sets up Kafka as a source:

```java
// KafkaSource setup
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
    .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
    .setGroupId("stroke-risk-group")
    .setTopics(Arrays.asList("patient-data-topic"))
    .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.valueOnly(StringDeserializer.class))
    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
    .build();

DataStreamSource<String> patientData = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
```

I have already included the necessary Flink dependencies in my project, and I'm using Maven to build it. However, I'm still encountering this issue. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Code -> https://github.com/IshaanAdarsh/icu-alarm

**Additional Information:**

- Flink version: 1.16.2
- Java version: 11
- IDE used: IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Maven does not default to put your dependencies in the JAR. Please try again with shade or assembly maven plugins, not the default JAR plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed your pom.xml file and noticed that the scope of multiple dependencies is set to `provided`. This means that you're expected to load them manually.

By removing the scope or by changing it to `compile` it will retrieve the dependencies and load them automatically.

Make sure you run `mvn clean install` before attempting to run `StrokeRiskAlarm`.